# How can I remove the "hard science" notifice from my question?

Tags: support, questions, tags

I have a question that I had initially tagged [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science). I then changed my mind (before any answers came in) and changed the tag to [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based).

However, there is still the warning box: "This question asks for hard science", etcetera.

I believe they shouldn't be there anymore now that I've changed the question to [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based)?

How can I remove it?

Here is the question:

[Is it feasible to separate the Mediterranean from the rest of the world's oceans using dams?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55668/is-it-feasible-to-separate-the-mediterranean-from-the-rest-of-the-worlds-oceans)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Flag the post for moderator attention.** The post notice can only be added by moderators (or SE employees with mod powers), so we do this manually, and we remove it manually. Normally, we see when the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag is added to a question - I check the active tab of the tag's questions on a daily basis - but it's harder to see when the tag's removed. So please, use a custom mod flag, and let us know to remove it!

For the record, though, I'll go and remove the notice now on this question. I notice you flagged the question; thanks, this was the right thing to do.